# Vaadin + Spring Boot + JDBC + JDBC Session causing restart loop

Tags: session, vaadin, spring-jdbc

I am using Vaadin 24 and have tried the below with Vaadin 23 also.

I need to store session data related to user's activity so we tried using [Vaadin's Web Storage API](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/web-storage-api) and our code look like the Callback Ladder and was getting really unreadable and unmaintainable

So we decided trying good old HTTP Sessions with JDBC.
As per various blogs that we referred we added the following dependancies -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <!-- to be swapped with mysql later -->
</dependency>
```

But as soon as I have added these my application has gone into a continuous refresh loop.

I also tried the same on a fresh project from start.vaadin.com and added these dependancies to enter the reboot loop.
Please help we are blocked here.

I have pushed my sample code here - https://github.com/shubham-m/vaadin-jdbc-session-issue

I have tried using Vaadin version 23 got same result

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh loop"? What exact error/problem are you facing? What does the logging of your application tell you? Have you tried ramping up the log levels?

Comment: The home page of the application is continuously refreshing, no logs are seem on the server side. Network tabs show continuous loading of UI elements

Comment: You don't need the spring-session-jdbc. What are you trying to achieve?